# Scoring when two triple word squares are covered in one play

Tags: scrabble, scoring

The word QUAGMIRE is on the board vertically, with the Q on the top row, second column. The next player creates SQUEEZED horizontally, landing the S on the triple word square in the top row, first column, and remaining UEEZED landing to the right of the existing Q, ending with the D on the triple word square in the eighth column. Since two triple word squares are covered in this one placement, how would it be scored?

Letters:

- S: 1
- Q: 10
- U: 1
- E: 1 x 2 (double letter)
- E: 1
- Z: 10
- E: 1
- D: 1

27 Total for letters. Do you then multiply by 3 for the first triple word square, and then multiply that result by 3?

27 X 3 = 81,
81 X 3 = 243

Bonus for all 7 tiles placed:

243 + 50 = 293

Comment: lmao nice. I can just imagine the heated arguments between the players whether it's 6 or 9.

Answer (score 7):

If you cover two triple word scores in a single play, you mutliply your score by 9.  From [the scrabble rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules):

> If a word is formed that covers two premium word squares, the score is doubled and then re-doubled (4 times the letter count), or tripled and then re-tripled (9 times the letter count).

293 is the correct score for that play.  27 (for letters, counting the double letter score) * 9 (for both triple word scores) + 50 (for the bingo) = 293

Answer (score 4):

If you cover multiple bonus squares, all of their effects are applied -- multiple letter modifiers first, and the full word score added up, then all multiple word modifiers are applied.

That means that if you cover two triple word squares, your letter count (including the one double letter you cover along the way, assuming it wasn't already covered) is multiplied by three, and by three again, so total of nine times the letter count before adding the Bonus for a full tray play.

Your 293 seems like a correct count.